# Partial url in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, codeigniter

Fellow Coders,

so far I have been using the CI url helper to build full urls using base_url() and site_url(). Now I'm trying to access a controller function within some javascript code that will be loaded as a js file.

it's actually an ajax call with a url parameter that should be something like:

```
url : '/account/check_user'
```

now unless i prefix the url with the full path as ins http://servername/..... the code fails.

all the code examples i've seen use the short version of the url but i cannot get it to work. I'm sure this is really simple but i'm stuck.

i could pass a hidden form field to the js code but i'd rather not. any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I also tend to use *absolute URLs* and a good practice I always do is declaring a JS variable:

```
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
```

In:

1. the `head` section
2. as the first line of my `script` tag
3. if I have a `main.js` file that holds *most* of my JS code **AND** it's always included in my views, then I put that line first thing in the file.

After that, you use it like:

```
url : base_url + 'account/check_user'
```

Anyway, the first slash `/` in your url tells the browser to go to the URL root which would not be the right place to put your url chunk in! for example:
if your CI installation is in `ci` folder and your URL is: `domain.com/ci/contorller/method/`
Then your URL will become: `domain.com/contorller/method/`!!

Comment: hmmm, didn't think about adding the variable setting code in the script tag within my template php file!!! I had to use site_url instead of base_url to include index.php as part of the url.  funny thing is that i use base_url when loading js and css files and that works fine.  that index.php file always gives me trouble! thanks to both @ifaour and @polarblau for the quick answers!!! cheers :)

Comment: I've just been too focused on the code (and a bit lazy) to look into removing index.php :)

Comment: @djeetee: lol, seriously?! first time I used CI, I said WTF `index.php` is doing up there! it's just plain ugly! :P

Comment: I agree it is ugly! getting rid of it is proving to be more ugly. I followed the CI Wiki, instructions on various sites, you name it and i'm having no luck. I will post a question about that in a sec.

Answer (score 3):

I'm usually assigning the base_url() to a JS variable right in the head to have it available to all methods. Something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = "<?php echo base_url() ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: fyi short tags are deprecated now, best to use <?php echo base_url(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You should actually be using CI's site_url() function. base_url() is useful for generating a URL to a resource (such as script or stylesheet), but site_url() is the best choice when generating a URL to a page within the app itself, such as when making an Ajax request, as described.

So the best code to use would be something along these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var site_url = "<?php echo site_url() ?>";
</script>
```